# Local datastore write methods do not return (e.g..: pin(), pinAll(), unpin(), unpinAll())

Tags: android, parse-platform, local-datastore

I'm building an android app using the Android Parse SDK, which gets all data from Parse at initialisation and stores it locally. Later, it will only update those entities (ParseObjects) which need so. I'm not getting any return from some Pin() operations, and similarly no callback when I use PinInBackground() and variants. Same happens with Unpin().

My code is something like the following. I have a list of ControlDate, a ParseObject which contains updated_at and updated_locally_at for each Parse data table. I use it to decide if I should query a given table (reducing number of queries). I iterate over this list when I perform a data update, in an IntentService, like this:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

for(ControlDate d : mUpdateQueue) { // mUpdateQueue is the list of ControlDate
    if(d.entityNeedsUpdate()) { // returns true if updated_at > updated_locally_at   
        updateEntity(d);
    }   
}

private boolean updateEntity(ControlDate d) {
    String tableName = d.getTableName();   
    Date lastLocalUpdate = d.getLastLocalUpdate();
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> qParse = ParseQuery.getQuery(tableName);  
    qParse.whereGreaterThan("updated_at", lastLocalUpdate);    
    try {   
        // update the entities       
        List<ParseObject> entities = qParse.find();       
        ParseObject.pinAll(entities); // SOMETIMES GETS STUCK (no return)

        // update the associated ControlDate       
        d.setLastLocalUpdate(new Date());  // updated_locally_at = now
        d.pin();  // SOMETIMES GETS STUCK (no return)
    }   
    catch(ParseException e) {   
         // error
    }   
}

}
```

Those operations SOMETIMES do not return. I'm trying to find a pattern but still no luck, apparently it started happening when I added pointer arrays to some of the entities. Thus, I think it may be due to the recursive nature of pin(). However it is strange that it sometimes also gets stuck with ParseObjects which do not reference any others - as it is the case with d.pin().

Things I've tried:

- changing the for loop to a ListIterator (as I am changing the list of ControlDates, but I don't think this is necessary);
- using the threaded variants (eg.: PinInBackground()) - no callback;
- pinning each entity individually (in a loop, doing pin()) - a lot slower, still got stuck;
- debugging - the thread just blocks here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNnVS.png

I'm going crazy with this, help would be much appreciated!

PS.: I found this https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android/issues/48
Its an open issue on the bolts library, which is used in the Android SDK and may be causing this (maybe?). Anyway I cannot see how I could overcome my problem even though the cause for the pin() not returning could be an "unobserved exception" leading to a deadlock.

Comment: Same problem here. I detected it only happens on the first pin after app launch. So if this pin goes well, the rest goes well too.

Comment: Yeah well I 'solved' this by ditching Parse localstore completely. Now using Realm.io and a custom solution to save Parse objects locally. Unfortunately there appears to be no answer to this problem at the moment.